# Why is MediaQuery.of(context).size.height in Flutter detecting a larger height in Android chromium-based browsers?

Tags: flutter, chromium

[**Here is the repo**](https://github.com/joelc0193/flutter_screen_height_bug/tree/1face61a465d7858501bec434bbefa4efded64c5)

My widget is not loading correctly according to the screen size in Android chromium-based mobile browsers. It is being displayed too long vertically. In the code below, all I do is display a black container with yellow borders, that takes up the whole screen. When the container is initially rendered, the bottom border does not show up, because it is below the screen. I have to tap the screen in order for it to adjust then the container fits perfectly in the screen.

Also, I don't show it in this example, but when I display `MediaQuery.of(context).size.height` in a text widget in the middle of the screen, it says `1122` before tapping, then changes to `738` after tapping. It genuinely somehow has the wrong height initially.

This only happens in chromium-based browsers. This does not happen on Edge or Opera.

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
 @override
 State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}


class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Container(
     decoration: BoxDecoration(
       color: Colors.black,
       border: Border.all(
         color: Colors.yellow,
         width: 3.0,
       ),
     ),
   );
 }
}
```

Before Tap (Bottom border extends beyond page):
[image: Before Tap]

After Tap (Bottom border fits in page):
[image: After Tap]

Comment: Check out this summary by Pixeltoast on the fundamentals of Flutter layout including MediaQuery: https://notes.tst.sh/flutter/media-query/

Comment: @RandalSchwartz Even if I do not use Media Query, the container is still too tall. Anything that I use, flutter renders it too tall. I was only using Media Query to show you the height that Flutter thinks it is working with, when in reality the actual height is less.

Comment: what is your real purpose? Just know why the heigth is different? or make the container fill all space on device?

Comment: @Alaindeseine to know why the height given to flutter is not the actual height

Comment: Flutter version, browser name and version?

Comment: may i ask why you need media query? what you are trying to achieve?
i might provide a work around

Comment: can't reproduce this issue with latest flutter version

Comment: add the code to reproduce the issue

Comment: @Cabdirashiid https://github.com/joelc0193/flutter_screen_height_bug/tree/1face61a465d7858501bec434bbefa4efded64c5

Comment: @AngDrew https://github.com/joelc0193/flutter_screen_height_bug/tree/1face61a465d7858501bec434bbefa4efded64c5

Comment: @SayyidJ https://github.com/joelc0193/flutter_screen_height_bug/tree/1face61a465d7858501bec434bbefa4efded64c5

Comment: @diegoveloper https://github.com/joelc0193/flutter_screen_height_bug/tree/1face61a465d7858501bec434bbefa4efded64c5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in Android Chrome-based browsers that I already reported.
I was talking to a Google Flutter web engineer and he told me that it's something that needs to be fixed in the engine.

This is the issue link: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/145667

I'll let you know if there is a solution you can use.

Answer (score 0):

This could be related to how these browsers handle initial rendering and layout calculations. To address this issue, you can try forcing a layout update after the initial rendering to ensure that the widget sizes correctly. One way to achieve this is by using a LayoutBuilder widget to wrap your Container and trigger a rebuild after the initial layout is complete.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  bool hasAdjusted = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (context, constraints) {
        // Check if the layout has been adjusted
        if (!hasAdjusted) {
          // Trigger a rebuild with updated constraints
          WidgetsBinding.instance?.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
            setState(() {
              hasAdjusted = true;
            });
          });
        }

        // Return your container
        return Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.black,
            border: Border.all(
              color: Colors.yellow,
              width: 3.0,
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

By using LayoutBuilder, we can check if the layout has been adjusted. If not, we trigger a rebuild after the initial layout using WidgetsBinding.instance?.addPostFrameCallback. This ensures that the widget sizes correctly after the initial rendering, hopefully resolving the issue you're encountering with the bottom border not displaying properly in certain Chromium-based mobile browsers.